# Failing to start Postgres SQL Server on Centos

Tags: centos, postgresql

I just followed this tutorial:

http://www.unixmen.com/postgresql-9-4-released-install-centos-7/

But I can't start my postgres sserver on my centOS 6.5 machine.

Here's the error:

```
[root@vm5 ~]# service postgresql-9.4 initdb
Data directory is not empty!
[root@vm5 ~]# service postgresql-9.4 start                 [FAILED]
Starting postgresql-9.4 service:                           [FAILED]
[root@vm5 ~]# /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.4 start
Starting postgresql-9.4 service:                           [FAILED]
```

Before that tutorial I had already tried this one:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: tail the log file and see what it outputs on the service starting

Comment: One can only guess.   It looks like there is an already existing installation - maybe the permissions are wrong.   If not, move/remove the old installation and re-init the DB.

Comment: @davidgo I don't know how to do that

Comment: @Rudolph log file is empty

Comment: Can't help you without more knowledge of "where you are at" - and if you are running a Postgres database you may well want to beef up on your sysadmin skills.  You might want to follow the steps of totally removing postgres and reinstalling - see https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=32438

Comment: X-post from http://stackoverflow.com/q/27670841/398670

Answer (score 0):

Centos complains because she found you have something there already.  She is so kind that she did not wants to destroy something that might be precious for you.

This non empty folder might be:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/data
```

If not, then issue the command:

```
find / -name pg_hba.conf
```

the folder where this file resides should be empty.  Remove the contents.
then try to re-init.

fails again?

Try this command:

```
chown -R postgres:postgres data
```

May be this will help .....